# Autoupdate labels on HTML page every Get request

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I need to update in realtime one or more labels on my HTML webpage, im using some .css and .js for the animations on the webpage.

Actually im using flask for manage the calls.

I need to update the values of the html page everytime that i receive a GET on my flask webserver.
How could I do?
Im not so familiar with webapps, i need some help about technologies and techinques.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to do so would be by using vue.js
There you can assign the content in your DOM (more exactly your vue-component) to a variable which you can update on every request.

Alternatively you can use your standart js and update each label with the content on your label-update...

Comment: is it possible update a label when my website receive a get request using javascript? @Skolak

Comment: You mean, you sent a request from the Browser(Website) to your Server and get the new Labels as an answer?
In this case: yes, you can process the answer and set the content in the DOM to the content you get from answer of the request.